# How to run method and while it is working keep my application running (don't wait for method to finish her job)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datagrid

I'm working on small C# application, that application has one DataGrid on main screen and items in it, application has one purpose: when user press F9 it will loop throught DataGrid items and write that items from datagrid in notepad and send that notepad to a FISCAL PRINTER (that means put that notepad file to path where printer is listening). (* **Explanation what is fiscal printer**: that is small printer which is waiting for notepad files on some location i.e (C:\MyFiles), and if you give him correct file he will proceed it ->it means paper with items will come out of printer, price, item title etc, and printer will put his own file where he's telling is everything ok, and also printer will write there one special number that is called FISCAL NUMBER ID*), **now lets back to C# code!**

So I did everything, everything is working fine, but there is one issue:

When I leave correct file in folder where printer is listening, printer will take it, and my application will keep listening for printer's file because application must read that FISCAL NUMBER ID from that printers file.

And here comes my problem, because application must listen for printer to answer, and to read his file to put that FISCAL NUMBER ID to database etc that takes a lot time, like 3-4 seconds, so while that is happening it is impossible to click anywhere on my application or smth like that, it simply freezes!

So my question is how could I put this method in a thread or something so it can do her job while my application is still responsive to user clicks/requests.

Here is my code when user PRESS F9:

```
 if (e.Key == Key.F9)
            {
                try
                {

                        if (dtgStavke.Items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Printer printer = new Printer();
                            printer.AdressAnswer = "C:\\MyPrinterFiles\\";
                            printer.AdressError = "C:\\MyPrinterFiles\\Errors\\";
                            printer.AdressExit = "C:\\MyPrinterFiles\\Good\\";


                            Bill newBill = new Bill();

                            newBill.OrdinalNumber = Convert.ToInt32(BillController.Instance.GetNextBillOrdinalNumber())+1;
                            newBill.Reversed = false;
                            newBill.Fiscalized = false; 
                            newBill.BFF = 0;
                            newBill.BRR = 0;

                            newBill.TotalAmount = stavkeTemp.Sum(x => (x.Price*x.Quantity));
                            newBill.TotalWithoutTax = totalWithoutTAXGlobal;
                            newBill.TotalTax = totalTaxGlobal;

                            if (_globalCustomer != null)
                            {
                                if (_globalCustomer.Status == 1)
                                {
                                    newBill.CompanyId = _globalCustomer.Id;
                                }
                                else
                                    newBill.PersonId = _globalCustomer.Id;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                newBill.CompanyId = 1;
                                newBill.PersonId = 1;
                                newBill.UserId=1;
                            }
                            Bill lastInsertedBill = BillController.Instance.Save(newBill);
                            }

                            bool succeed = Print(lastInsertedBill, p, printer, _globalCustomer, false);
                        }

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

How could I isolate this to a new thread or something like that, I tried few things but it is definately not working?

There is Print method and everything is happening there:

file making

waiting for answer to read printer's file

again updating database with that fiscal printer id from that printers file

So must of the work is happenig there, so It would be nice to isolate it somehow, to keep my application responsive to user requestes while `Print` method is doing her job

```
bool succeed = Print(lastInsertedBill, p, printer, _globalCustomer, false);
```

Thanks guys
Cheers!

Comment: You need to read about async await in C#

Comment: @Sparrow is that something like threading, and I will definately read about it now

Comment: asynchronous programming is different from multi threading, but it is designed to do what you you want.

Comment: You can't access UI elements from a non-UI thread. Keep that in mind with your solution.

Comment: @Enigmativity can you post one example please?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro - You want an example of not accessing a UI element from a non-UI thread?

Comment: @Enigmativity simply explanation what does it mean acctualy

Comment: @Roxy'Pro - It's fairly straight forward. All access to UI elements must happen on the UI thread. If you start a new thread or task you then can't access any UI element. So before you can do any processing on another thread you must extract all of the data you want to use into some sort of data structure that doesn't involve any UI element, do your processing on that, and then return the results in another data structure via an `.Invoke(...)` call on a UI element to allow the data to update the UI.

Answer (score 2):

The easy answer would be if you could make it with async await like Sparrow already mentioned.

The call to Print would afterwards look like this:

```
bool succeed = await Task.Run(()=>Print(lastInsertedBill, p, printer, _globalCustomer, false)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The method signature of the code where your whole code construct is in has to change as well. So imagine your current signature looks like this:

```
public void KeyPressed(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

It should change to look afterwards like this:

```
public async Task KeyPressed(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

These changes would make your Print method run in a different Task (which is simply said a more efficient way of utilizing other Threads). So in this way your UI-Thread is free to do stuff while another Background-Thread does your Print job.

If you want to read up on async await I'd recommend this [blog by Stpehen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) as a starting point. And a book that helped me a lot regarding async await was "Async in C# 5.0" by Alex Davies. It has only 108 pages, is really good written and you gain all the knowledge you need.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, I was sick so I couldn't do anything about that, and what about running new task? Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ... I saw people are using it so much? It is same like async await?

Comment: Task.Factory.StartNew was the initial and only way to start a new Task. But with .net 4.5 a new way of starting a new Task came which is Task.Run. Simply said Task.Run is an overload of Task.Factory.StartNew that handles the most common cases of creating a new Task. For more info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/

Comment: and what is different between them and solution you offered with async and await?

Comment: I explained it in the simple way already. For more detailed information regarding their difference please refer to the blog post I mentioned. As you can see in my answer: I utilized Task.Run to pass the workload of your Print method to a separate Task. The async keyword tells the compiler that a method is an asynchronous method and the await keyword tells the compiler to execute the code written below it only after the background Task has finished its work.